# Se puede mejorar el motor de búsquedas de Datatables Jquery?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Tengo mi datatable, que hago un filtro de inputs por columna, al buscar en una columna maria m, me despliega todos los valores que tengan esa coincidencia o tengan maria o tengan una m, pero vi en un plugin yadcf que cuando pongo maria m, solo me muestra las coincidencia maria maria, maria miriam por lo tanto es mas exacto, existe alguna configuracion que se deba de realizar en el datatables para tener este efecto??

Answer (score 1):

Puedes modificar el `filter` de tu tabla, creas un `input` donde ingresas el nombre que quieres filtrar

```
<input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="ingresa nombre">
<button id="filtrar">Filtrar</button>
```

Defines la funcion que se encargara de hacer el filtro

```
var filterByName = function(column, name) {
    $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
       function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
          var rowName = aData[column]; //Aqui obtienes el valor de la columna.
        //Y comparas si son iguales.
          if(rowName == name){
             return true;
          }
       }
    );
};
```

Defines el evento `click` para capturar el evento del boton y llamas a la funcion de filtrar.

```
$('#filtrar').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var name = $("#name").val(); //Guardas el valor del input


   filterByName(0, name); //0 es la columna, imaginando el la primera columna es nombre la dejas en 0 y envias name que es lo que ingresaste

   $tableSel.dataTable().fnDraw();
});
```

Este es un ejemplo, para obtener el valor que esperas necesitas modificar la funcion de filtro y ver por ejemplo, si quieres saber el nombre exacto, si el nombre contiene lo que ingreso el usuario en fin, puedes modificar el filtro. Tambien puedes en vez de esperar el `click`, capturar el evento `keyup` y cada vez que ingrese una letra o numero en el input vaya filtrando.